# How to write frontend tests for ECharts in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, frontend, echarts

I am using Apache ECharts in my Angular project.
ECharts is generating a HTML canvas and rendering the graphics inside of the canvas.
I want to write a test to check if my data is represented in the rendered graph accordingly.
But the canvas object itself doesn't contain anything when the graphic is rendered. (Most probably the canvas is populated by JavaScript)

Could you please let me know if there is any way to write a frontend test for this case?

I tried to test the rendered graphics with the rendered HTML, but I wasn't able to find any data in the HTML through this strategy.
Another strategy would be testing the typescript functions, but again, I want to be sure that my data is *rendered* correctly.